# Finding functions satisfying modular identity similar to Euler's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

From Euler's Theorem, we have the well known identity

$$a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n \quad ; \quad \gcd(a,n) =1$$

What other similar identities of the form

$$f(a,n) \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

for non trivial functions $f$ are known?

Answer (score 1):

[Carmichael function](https://www.google.lt/search?dcr=0&source=hp&ei=EF73WdTAFubB6QSW-rugCQ&q=carmichael+function&oq=carmichael+function&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203k1l3j0i22i30k1l7.218.2720.0.2859.24.15.1.0.0.0.266.1991.1j6j4.11.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..12.12.1993.0..0j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i67k1j0i10i203k1.0.Z_M5JeQ9x60). Let $n$ be a positive integer. $\lambda(n)$ is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $$a^{k}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$$ for all $a\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\gcd(a,n)=1$. $$\lambda(p^{\alpha})=\begin{cases}\phi(p^{\alpha}),\ \text{ if }\alpha\le 2\text{ or }p\ge 3\\\frac{1}{2}\phi(p^{\alpha}),\ \text{ if }\alpha\ge 3\text{ and }p=2\end{cases}$$

If $p_i$ are different prime numbers, then $$\lambda(p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k})=\text{lcm}(\lambda(p_1^{\alpha_1}),\ldots,\lambda(p_k^{\alpha_k}))$$

Comment: It's more or less similar to Euler's Theorem. Note that I'm asking for different functions $f$ such that the modular equation holds, not different powers of $a$ which give the identity.